# Unable to create a table under dbo schema

Tags: sql-server

Docker environment:
Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU10) (KB5031778) - 16.0.4095.4 (X64)

I created a database - testdb

Created a login and user name

```
use testdb
create login adarsh with password = 'table@123';
use testdb;
create user adarsh_user for login adarsh;
```

Created a schema

```
use testdb;
grant create schema to adarsh_user;
```

gave permission t create tables

```
use testdb;
grant CREATE TABLE to adarsh_user;
```

I connect to testdb as adarsh_user.

```
use testdb;
create table [testdb].[adarsh_schema].[ads_1512_0536]( fam_member_id smallint, firstname text, lastname text);
```

This is successful.

```
use testdb;
create table ads_1512_0457( fam_member_id smallint, firstname text, lastname text);
```

> The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

```
SELECT permission_name, state_desc FROM sys.database_permissions where grantee_principal_id = USER_ID('adarsh_user');
```

| permission_name | state_desc |
| --- | --- |
| CONNECT | GRANT |
| CREATE | SCHEMA |
| CREATE | TABLE |

```
USE testdb;
SELECT default_schema_name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name in('adarsh_user' );
```

| default_schema_name |
| --- |
| dbo |

Try to update again eventhough it is currently set as dbo

```
ALTER USER adarsh_user WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
```

Comment: The table name `ads_1512_0457` in your select is not the same as the table you created  `testdb].[adarsh_schema].[ads_1512_0536]`. Also, not sure how your server is configured, but typically if you don't specify the schema (as you didn't in your select) it _assumes_ you meant `dbo`. Do you actually have a table named `dbo.ads_1512_0457`?

Comment: Why are the tables named like this? Why not use *one* table with an extra discriminator column? Are you trying to implement "partitioning" by using multiple copies of the same table? There's no reason to do this, SQL Server offers transparent partitioning in all supported versions and editions

Comment: You have not granted permissions on the `dbo` schema to the user. Setting the default schema does not confer permissions.

Comment: @Xedni I gave the SQLs to show that on schema adarsh_schema I am able to create, whereas I am unable to on dbo( when schema name is not specified). ads_1512_0457 is the table i am trying to create on dbo.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just started to learn sql server, and the names are created with date and time just to not waste time thinking for suitable names. Nothing more than that.

Comment: That's not a great idea. It makes it harder to understand your own code

Comment: @DanGuzman I have granted table create permission and I have pasted the output from sys.database_permissions in the content. Please recheck, and let me know whether you are referring to anything different

Comment: @techentusiast, there is no grant to the user for the `dbo` schema. I believe `ALTER` is the minimum needed to create objects: `GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO adarsh_user;`

Comment: @DanGuzman after granting alter I am able to, thanks. But I am wondering why it did not allow when I had create table privilege. My understanding from reading was that create table privilege is given for a database and not schema ( also because when I gave grant create table on schema::dbo to adarsh_user; it gave syntax error) and when a user has create table privilege, it can create under any schema under that table. Would be great if you could add a little more details for me to understand whats happening here.

Comment: @techentusiast, I elaborated with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE` at the database level simply allows one to execute a `CREATE TABLE` statement. Granting `CREATE TABLE` (or setting the user's default schema) does not confer permissions on schemas. The user also needs at least `ALTER` on schemas which will contain new tables.

For the `dbo` schema:

```
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO adarsh_user;
```

Comment: Remember never grant ALTER on a schema to a non-admin.  Instead ALTER AUTHORIZATION on the schema to make them schema owners.  The ability to create objects in other users’ schema allows escalation of privileges through ownership chains.